# Populating a JTable from Access Database

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I am trying to populate a JTable with data from a database. I've tried so many different ways and it just doesn't want to work. Currently I have a class which returns a resultset with the entire database to my UIClass which then uses the resultset to populate the JTable. Bellow is my method that retrieves the resultset and then populates the JTable.

```
     private void SetJTable()
  {
 int count = 0;
 String boatclass, senior, under23, junior;

 try
 {
 ResultSet results = object.AllWorldBestTimes();
 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Times.getModel();

 model.addColumn("Boat Class");
 model.addColumn("Senior");
 model.addColumn("Under 23");
 model.addColumn("Junior");

     while(count<24)
     {
        boatclass = results.getString(1);
        senior = results.getString(2);
        under23 = results.getString(3);
        junior = results.getString(4);

        System.out.println(boatclass + senior + under23 + junior);
        model.insertRow(Times.getRowCount(), new Object[]{boatclass, senior, under23, junior});
        count++;
     }
  Times = new JTable(model);
 }
 catch (SQLException e)
 {
  System.out.println("Ef");
 }
}
```

Here is the method of retrieving data from the database:

```
     public ResultSet AllWorldBestTimes() throws SQLException
{
  DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();

  ResultSet result = connection.SelectStatements("SELECT * FROM WorldBestTimes");

  return result;
}
```

there is no crash so i cannot give the stack trace, nor does it go into the catch statement.

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
model.insertRow(Times.getRowCount(), ...
```

Times.getRowCount() is always going to return zero, since it's empty.

```
Times = new JTable(model);
```

Reassigns the reference Times, but it doesn't take the old table out of the form or add the new one into the form.

Try this...

```
model = new DefaultTableModel();
```

...and this...

```
model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), ...
```

...and this...

```
Times.setModel(model);
```

Hard to say if that will do it or not. The code sample isn't exactly SCCE.